# Bootstrap-3 not working: it's working in one laptop but not in another.why is this so?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, web-development-server

Me and my friend are working on this webpage together and we have this same code. Now the code is working fine in my PC, I get the navbar and everything working perfectly. But for him, the `bootstrap` isn't working. Why is this so? and how can we fix this?
Also, we are using the `Xampp` server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Purrfect Match</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Purrfect Match</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="about_index.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="imageGallery.html">Gallery</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="online_signup.html">Sign in <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
               <div id="content">
                  <h1>Purrfect Match</h1>
                  <h3>The Only Human-Canine Dating App</h3>
                  <hr>
                  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"  onclick ="window.location.href = 'quiz.html';"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> Get Started</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
         integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need a lot more informations to help you. What is the code that is working on your laptop, but not on your friends ? What versions of bootstrap / jquery are you using ? What browsers are you using ? When you say you have the same code, is it 100% the same code, or are you just assuming it is ?

Comment: As above and: are there any errors in the console or network tab?  Such as 404/403 on a .js/.css file?   "isn't working" isn't enough information - does it work but there's no styles?  Are there styles but the menu is always / never visible?

Comment: I have now provided the code, @Lapskaus it's a hundred percent the same code as I mailed it to him. Bootstrap version: 3.3.7 and jquery version: 2.2.4

Comment: also, it's not working here refers to navbar showing as plain text and not as it is supposed to.

Comment: @freedomn-m There are no errors in the console. The Plain text of the navbar is visible but the styles are not that is the menu of the navbar is visible as a plain text with a link.

Comment: Thats usually an indication that the css files did not load correctly. Is he online and able to download the css files from the CDN's?

Comment: you are using `CDN` so make sure your friend is connected to the internet. But sometimes not connecting to the internet works because the browser you are using saves the file as a `cache` so, that it doesn't need to load them every time. Just give a try by downloading the `bootstrap` link it internally.

Comment: as kedar suggested above, check for internet na dhow you send him this code in mail? is it attached zip or plain text in mail body?

Comment: @kedarsedai My friend is connected to the internet. He also tried downloading the bootstrap internally but it still didn't work.

Comment: @AtulRajput internet is connected. I sent him a google drive link which contains the entire code in a zip file.

Comment: can you paste that sharable link here pls

Comment: @Lapskaus yes, he's online and he downloaded the files and then tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you running your code from a server?  You mention Xampp - are you sure your friend is running it via the server `http://localhost/...` and *not* opening the files directly `file://C:\users...\desktop\..` (or so)?

Comment: yes, he is running it from the server.